# @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS) not working in a microservices context

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

When trying to serialize/deserialize a generic object to a specific class,
I ran into the following problem:

The code:

```
// Generic holding the payload data linked to this event
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Request.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Decision.class)
})
private P payload;
```

Unfortunately, this resolves to a @class property with the entire classpath in it. For example:

```
com.***.***.request.entity.Request
```

Since I'm using microservices, the classpath is slightly different.
On the receiving end, it should be:

```
com.***.***.dossier.entity.Request
```

I don't know how to fix this.
I tried with MINIMAL_PATH and CUSTOM too.

Any other suggestions on how to correctly (de)serialize generics are welcome too.

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Second suggestion

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResourceReference.class, name = "resourceReference"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Request.class, name = "request")
})
private P payload;
```

example to which P should deserialize:

```
@JsonTypeName("request")
public class Request {}
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#highlighter_505170

Answer (score 1):

It's almost never a good idea to use `CLASS` for the type info, even though it's the default; it causes unnecessary coupling to internals and makes migration difficult. Use `NAME` instead, with a sensible `@JsonTypeName`, such as `FooRequest`.

Comment: What if there are multiple possibilities? I can't choose a static name. The payload can be one of multiple possible objects.

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans That's the purpose of `@JsonTypeName`; you apply it to the polymorphic options. If for some reason they're not under your control, you can still use something like Jackson mixins.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is a little to vague. Should I do nothing but add @JsonTypeName annotations to the classes it should deserialize to?
What should I write on top of "P payload"? If I write nothing there, Jackson will serialize it as some sort of LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Jackson's _serialization_ is indistinguishable whether you use a POJO or a `Map`. The _deserialization_ depends on type inference, and using `@JsonTypeInfo` is sufficient; I've done this exact case plenty of times. I refer you to the Jackson documentation for `@JsonTypeInfo` and in particular the `NAME` option, where this is discussed in detail.

Comment: I made an edit to my original post. It's where I tried to implement what you're suggesting (I think). See anything wrong with that?

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans First, I recommend against specifying either `include` or `property` (the defaults are usually best); to figure out your other problem, we'd need to see the JSON, the entire containing class being deserialized, and your code calling `readValue` or such.